# Discord Bot: Have a AttributeError with decorator command()

Tags: python, discord, bots, attributeerror

I'm a begginer in python,so I need your help. Now I'm trying to create a bot calculater, but I have the error that I did not understand and I've found nothing about it.

```
@client.command()
async def roll(ctx, arg=7):
   author = ctx.message.author
   runnum = random.randint(0,arg)
   await ctx.send(f"{author.mention}, ваш бросок равен ".format(runnum))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pACW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `discord.Client` if you want to use commands.

Use `commands.Bot`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#commands